Having trouble using an ESP32 dev board to control MOSFETs
I am trying to control a MOSFET using an ESP32 dev board, but I am having issues. Any time I put actual load through the MOSFET, the voltage across it drops significantly, and I cannot figure out the reason why.
Here is the wiring diagram, if this sketch can even be called that.

Model numbers:

ESP32 board: ESP32-WROOM-32
MOSFET: P30N06LE N-channel MOSFET

The basics of it are I have a 12V power adapter going through a DC buck converter to step down the voltage to 5V for the ESP32. The ESP32 then controls the MOSFET through a GPIO pin. I have a 220 Ohm resistor between the GPIO pin and the MOSFET gate pin to limit current, and a 10 KOhm resistor between the GPIO and GND as a pull-down resistor.
Under no load, this setup appears to work. I measure 0V across the drain pin and 12V until I set the GPIO high, at which point I measure the full 12V. However, as soon as I put any load, such as a small PC case fan or a load resistor, the voltage drops significantly (down to 3v trying to power a 12V 0.7W fan). I also hear some hissing noise coming from the buck converter when there is a load, suggesting that maybe the load's current is for some reason trying to flow across it.
Do I have something wired incorrectly, or am I missing something obvious here? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

As you can see in my answer, your MOSFET is not turning fully on.  You either need to get a 3.3V logic level MOSFET or implement my solution.

I drive IRLZ44N fets right from an esp32 gpio and they work well. if you are stuck with your fet, a "logic level adapter" circuit (search) will fix it.

You have a logic level MOSFET from 20 years ago when "logic" was 5V
It's going to need some sort of amplifier to boost 3.3V produced by the ESP32 up to 5V
eg: 74HCT1G34

You have 12V available but you are using 3.3V to turn the MOSFET on?
Even though your MOSFET is a LOGIC LEVEL MOSFET, it was meant for 5V logic, while your ESP32 works at and outputs a 3.3V level logic.
Your problem is that the MOSFET is not fully turned on with 3.3V Vgs and thus it has higher than specified ON resistance, so at the lightest load it seems fine, but with any significant load you have a large voltage drop.
You should have used 2.5V or 3.3V LOGIC LEVEL MOSFET.
Since you have 12V available, you could implement this simple addition to your circuit without changing the MOSFET:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You will need to modify a part of your code which defines your output to the MOSFET.
Specifically, you need to invert it so that it gives a HIGH output when it was LOW before and vice versa, because the NPN transistor here inverts its logic.
If you would rather not, or don't know how to, change the code, you could make a slightly more complex circuit without inverting the logic, for example like this:

simulate this circuit
If the circuit is in a noisy environment and/or your circuit turns on by itself sometimes (without a turn-on signal from ESP32), you could make it more reliable by placing 100kΩ resistors between bases and emitters of both transistors to make sure they stay off without an input signal.

You may find the graphic which shows Vgs to Id as follows:
Edit: Graphic from: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf page 4

So if your load draws more current than your MOSFET supplies this might be the problem. You need to follow @Edin Fifić's advice or just simply change your MOSFET with a lower Vgs threshold value. You may just look those graphics at datasheets and you will solve it.
